# .htaccess to execute other version of python

Tags: .htaccess

on my wev server python is by default 2.4
I also have python 2.5 which I want to make sefault via .htaccess file.

what's the directive to make /usr/bin/python2.5 the default python?

10x

Comment: not sure there's a way with .htaccess, but you could make the shebang line in your scripts: #!/usr/bin/python2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one. Specify it in the shebang line of the CGI scripts you want it to run.

Comment: Can`t I at least direct python to /usr/bin/python2.5 from .htacess?is there no aliasing mechanism??

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Python as a CGI binary, look for a shebang line in each CGI script. For example, change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.5
```

That's the way CGI works; it's not possible to specify a default in `.htaccess`.